# Store time in 12-hour format in SQLite and some calculations on it in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, time

I am working on some time stuff on Android. I get the time from a TimePicker and I want to store it in the database. I want to store time in a 12-hour format.

I also need to do some calculations on that time. If I store it as a `String`, it will involve a lot of coding to do calculations on that String.

Is there a better solution?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to *store* it in a 12-hour format or do you just want to *display* it in 12-hour format?

Comment: actually I want to do calculations on that time also I want to display time in 12-hour format

Comment: It's usually better to store data in a universal format (like 24-hour clock for times) and then convert it into your specific format at display time using your language's date and time functions.

Comment: any material available regarding this. will I be able to do calculations in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to store time as Unix timestamps:

- Easy calculations (you can just add and subtract time in seconds, so to add an hour you add 60*60 = 3600 seconds)
- Easy formatting: the Java Date and DateFormat classes can easily handle Unix timestamps.

Example of 12 hour formatting:

```
public String getDateFormatted(Date datum) {
        DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy K:m a"); //example: 05/23/2012 11:34 PM
        return dfm.format(datum);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my androidapp i am storing datetime as long in java and database.
(Unix Time, number of seconds since 1970-01-01. as @hawaii.five-0 stated)

These numbers can easily be compared for earlier/later dates but are hard to read for a human when looking into raw database.

For displaying dates these long numbers are converted back to java Date with `new Date(longValue)`.

Comment: +1 this is the best way to do it.  Although strings are easily readable, it's far easier to make mistakes with them, but when does anybody actually look at a SqlLite db in raw form anyway?  Unix time FTW

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately sqlite does not support Date format... Take a look at [sqlite affinity.](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

So you have to store  it in text or numeric format.. And apply your computations after retriving it from the database..